# Create a file in linux of size 128k which has data has 128k ones

Tags: linux, file, unix, dd

I want to create a file in linux of size 128k which has data has 128k ones. 
What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: Bytes of all ones (decimal 255) or bytes containing the ASCII code for digit one, ot something else?

Comment: With all "0" it's easy (using /dev/null). But how to get all "1" ?

Comment: @tripleee all bits as 1.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you require the fastest solution, and fatest by what metric? Writing the bytes to the disk is probably going to be the bottleneck anyway, so it doesn't matter really how fast you generate them, as long as it's faster than the write rate of the output medium.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=131072 count=1 |
tr '\000' '\377' >file
```

Different variants of `tr` use slightly different syntax, so you may need to tweak this a bit.

Here's a memory-hogging but hopefully completely portable alternative;

```
perl -e 'printf("\xff" x 131072)' >file
```

Comment: What does **'\377'** mean ?

Comment: This command works fine in ubuntu but not in solaris. Do you know what change needs to be done for that?

Comment: `\377` is 255 in octal.

Comment: I don't have access to a Solaris environment. Which parts fail, how? Anyway, updated with an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

This is an order of magnitude faster than anything with `dd` :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE    (128*1024)
int main(){
   char *p=malloc(SIZE);
   memset(p,'\xff',SIZE);
   fprintf(stdout,p,SIZE);
}
```

Comment: "This is an order of magnitude faster than anything with dd" – I want to know why. Just because of no overhead of running dd?

Comment: @CharlieS Probably because `tr` has to do 128,000 lookups or `if` statements to decide whether each character needs translating and that is going to either involve lots of lookups or lots of branch predictions all of which slow things down. Mine simply writes a contiguous block of memory without testing anything and then writes that out without any further ado.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I would argue that your claim of an "order of magnitude" is most likely unjustified. Firstly because, on modern systems, the time take to write a mere 128KB is going to be nearly unmeasurable, and your above code, aside from error checking etc., is very close to what `dd` is likely doing anyway. `tr` will take a very little extra time because it's actually comparing and replacing bytes as they go by, but even that'll be minimal on this amount of data. Now, if the OP wanted a 2TB file of all ones, maybe you'd be able to measure a difference.

Comment: @twalberg Justified or not, that is what I actually measured. I averaged over 10,000 executions. I think it was a factor of 10.2.